# How do I stop Google featured snippets mixing my content up with another website?

Tags: seo, google-search, images, search-results, rich-snippets

On searching for 'fiduciary duty' I found that an image from a [page on my site](https://www.stakeholdermap.com/fiduciary-duty.html) is shown alongside text from another site in a featured snippet.

Search for 'fiduciary duty' in Google. The featured snippet shown below should appear. The snippet pulls content from two separate sites - law.cornell.edu and stakeholdermap.com.

[image: Google Search: featured snippet, linking to 'law.cornell.edu', but showing an image from 'stakeholdermap.com']

I want google to index the stakeholdermap.com image, because I want users to come to my website via the image.

The problem with the google snippet is that users will click the law.cornell page expecting to see the image in the article. My issue is that the law.cornell.edu page is getting most of the benefit from my image.

So, do I just accept this as I am at least getting some traffic OR should I try to stop Google from doing this?

Comment: So, is the site you linked to your own, or the one copying you? Please also link to the other site.

Comment: no one is copying anyone. Google is putting content from two sites together into the featured snippet.

Comment: Okay. Was the image yours; as in, did you have a license on it as your own disallowing others from using it?

Comment: My question is not about whether google is infringing copyright. It is whether the mash up they have done in the featured snippet is something I can stop. They are putting content from two separate sites into one result.

Comment: to clarify stakeholdermap.com is my site. law.cornell.edu is not owned by me and the image shown in the google snippet does not appear on law.cornell.edu.

Comment: So from what I can tell, the image is on your site, but the text is from law.cornell.edu. Does the image have a license on it, and is it your own?

Comment: The image is fine i purchased a license for it. My question is regarding how to stop google from putting content from my website alongside content from another in snippets. Google is making it look like the image appears on law.cornell.edu. When it actually appears on stakeholdermap.com/fiduciary-duty.html.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58400/discussion-between-hyper-neutrino-and-projectmonkey).

Comment: Google does some odd things and likely this is a result of an algorithm taking info from the knowledge graph. I will have to think on this a bit. If you do not care about image search, you can likely use robots.txt to keep Google from indexing the image. However, getting it removed from the knowledge graph will take longer. Otherwise, there is not something directly to be done.

Comment: Thanks closetnoc. I thought that might be the case. I want google to index the image, because I want users to come to my webpage via the image :) I am at least getting some traffic via this result, but the law.cornell.edu page is getting most of the benefit. It must seem odd to google users - they will click the law.cornell.edu article expecting to see the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue isn't replicating for me anymore
This is what I see in Safari on my Mac

[image]

Regardless the reason your image was used is because Cornell doesn't have an image and because your images ranks at first place (see the last image) it was used. It's a shame it doesn't link to your site but you've got to be proud that your image is ranked number one!

[image]